# ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F-'

Tags: xcode, clang, ld

I know this has been probably asked a thousands of times, but I can't get a rid of this error upon building. I think they started to show up after I upgraded Xcode to the latest version available (6.3.2).

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F-'
ld: library not found for -lPods-AcknowledgementsBundle
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

my Library Search Path (target) has:

```
$(inherited) non-recursive
$(PROJECT_DIR) non-recursive
```

I uninstalled and installed back the pod, clean and build.. nothing.

Does anybody have a good suggestion?
Thanks!